# Minify CSS and JS in CodeIgniter Efficiently

Tags: javascript, php, css, codeigniter, minify

So I am working on a project using the PHP framework CodeIgniter (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) and inside of it, we are using a lot of various CSS/JS files that are being called in our header include.

I've used the Minify tool before on WordPress sites and other projects, and ran across this library for CodeIgniter on GitHub (https://github.com/ericbarnes/ci-minify) and figured I would use it on my project.

It works all fine and dandy, but unfortunately I am compressing so many CSS and JS files that by the time the page loads, it would have been quicker if I *hadn't* used it.

Here's what the code looks like in my controller:

```
    // minify css
    $cssfiles = array('assets/css/normalize.css', 'assets/css/hook-new.css', 'assets/css/hook.css', 'assets/css/components.css', 'assets/css/rtl.css', 'assets/css/global.css', 'assets/css/body.css', 'assets/css/mediaqueries.css', 'assets/select2-3.4.3/select2.css', 'assets/jquery_bootstrap/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css');
    $cssfile = $this->minify->combine_files($cssfiles);
    $csscontents = $this->minify->css->min($cssfile);
    $this->minify->save_file($csscontents, 'assets/css/all.css');

    // minify js
    $jsfiles = array('assets/js/application/js_config.js', 'assets/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'assets/js/custom.js', 'assets/select2-3.4.3/select2.js', 'assets/js/startup.js', 'assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js', 'assets/js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js', 'assets/js/jquery.validationEngine.js', 'assets/js/scripts.js', 'assets/js/application/js_timer.js');
    $jsfile = $this->minify->combine_files($jsfiles);
    $jscontents = $this->minify->js->min($jsfile);
    $this->minify->save_file($jscontents, 'assets/js/all.js');
```

So I'm taking these large arrays of CSS and JS files, compressing them, then saving them to one large file. But is there a better and more efficient way of doing this?

I know I could combine them by hand, but then when I am working on things, I have massive files to sift through. Not only that, but I like Minify's ability to get rid of unnecessary white space and really condense the code.

So any thoughts on how I can efficiently accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: You should minify the files once, and put the compressed file on your server. Minifying the files every time they're requested is just crazy. Of course it's slow.

Comment: See, I don't think it is crazy. I could minify them all at ones, but what if I make a change to `body.css` and `mediaqueries.css`? Then I have to re-minify the files. That, or I have to go into this massive minified .css file, and find the lines I'm looking for.

Comment: @KeenanPayne I use the Grunt config I mentioned below and it doesn't take more than a few seconds on my 5+ years old MacBook to minify and concatenate all my CSS and JavaScript. You can even set it up to watch certain files and run the build task when they change automatically using grunt-contrib-watch (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why not use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)? You could set up a few tasks to concatenate and minify the JavaScript files. I've done this myself for a CodeIgniter project and it worked well. [Here's a tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/meeting-grunt-the-build-tool-for-javascript/).

Grunt is a Node.js-based tool, but since you'd be doing the build on your development machine this shouldn't be an issue - you won't need to have Node on the server. The idea is that before committing your changes, you run the build task which concatenates and minifies your JavaScript and CSS. Then your commit includes the minified files and you push them up to the server.

Here's a Gruntfile I used for my CodeIgniter project:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        concat: {
            dist: {
                src: ['static/bower_components/skeleton/stylesheets/*.css', 'static/css/style.css'],
                dest: 'static/css/main.css'
                }
            },
        uglify: {
            dist: {
                src: 'static/js/main.js',
                dest: 'static/js/main.min.js'
                }
            },
        cssmin: {
            dist: {
                src: 'static/css/main.css',
                dest: 'static/css/main.min.css'
                }
            }
        });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.registerTask('build', ['concat', 'uglify', 'cssmin']);
};
```

And the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "blah",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A project",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1.3",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.6.2",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jst": "~0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.4",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.4",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-contrib-csslint": "~0.1.2",
    "grunt-contrib-compress": "~0.5.2",
    "grunt-contrib-handlebars": "~0.5.11",
    "grunt-contrib-jade": "~0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-stylus": "~0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jasmine": "~0.5.2",
    "grunt-contrib-qunit": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.2.1",
    "grunt-contrib-yuidoc": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib": "~0.8.0"
  },
  "author": "My Name",
  "license": "licensename"
}
```

Comment: So if my website runs on Apache Server, this shouldn't be a problem? How do I install the NPM without NodeJS (following your link tutorial)?

Comment: You never run it on the server. You install Node.js, NPM and Grunt on your local machine and run it there, then commit the changes to version control and push them up to the server. The server used is irrelevant.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, because I only have the basic knowledge of nodejs - i install nodejs, npm and grunt on my local server, work on my website css/js files, and when done - I run grunt on my css and js files - and commit only the generated file? (I am just guessing it generates a file).

Comment: No. You install Node.js, NPM and Grunt on your local machine eg your laptop or desktop. You should commit both the source and the generated files.

Answer (score 1):

My personal solution since I use git and hook events, would be to have a php controller render this css and js file upon push and pull. That means, when you apply the new data, a hook executes this php script and rerender the file *once*.

In the hook bash script, run something like `php /var/www/index.php tool/minify` to run the controller's script.

Seems like a more ideal solution since the server only does this when it's actually required. If you need to do some on the fly testing, just run the render minified files once through controller when you update a css or js file manually.

- **[git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)**

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you might be interested in, I have written [this](https://github.com/alexcorvi/codeigniter-uglify) minifying (uglifying) library based on [Matthias Mullie](https://github.com/matthiasmullie) work on [minifier](http://minifier.org).

---

## [Library: CodeIgniter Uglify](https://github.com/alexcorvi/codeigniter-uglify)

### Installation

To install this class, simply upload the `src` folder contents from [github repo](https://github.com/alexcorvi/codeigniter-uglify/tree/master/src/ugly) to `application/libraries`. Then load the class using CodeIgniter's libarary loader:

```
$this->load->library("ugly/ugly");
```

### Usage Examples:

```
// minifying single string of code
// or single file
$result = $this->ugly->css("code goes here");
$result = $this->ugly->js("code goes here")
$result = $this->ugly->js("path/to/file")

// minifying multiple strings or files
$this->ugly->group_start("js");
// or $this->ugly->group_start("css");
$this->ugly->group_add("path/to/file");
$this->ugly->group_add("some code as string");
$result = $this->ugly->group_end();
```

Now you can save the result in a new file, or echo it, or whatever you want.

> **Notes:**
>
> - You can also pass an array of files:
>
>   - `$this->ugly->group_add( array("file1","file2","file2") );`.
> - You can also pass resources at the `group_start` method:
>
>   - `$this->ugly->group_start( array("file1","file2","file2") );`.

Comment: awesome, looks useful.

Answer (score 1):

Dude....grunt. it will save your life. Watch your sass/can/js files for changes and auto minify and concat into one js and one css file. It's amazing how much it will improve your load time and how easy it is.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Grunt.js](https://gruntjs.com/) for my **codeigniter** project to :

1. Concat **js** and **css** files into one file like `app.css` and `app.js`
2. Minify final **css** and **js** files

After installing **[Node.js](https://nodejs.org/)** in your development machine (Linux , windows or mac) you can install **grunt** and **grunt-cli** using **npm**  ( read Gruntjs document )

Then you can use this plugins on grunt :

1. [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) for concat css and js files into one file
2. [grunt-contrib-cssmin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin) for minify css files
3. [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) for minify js files

Then you can create Tasks for concating and minifying css and js files and Finally sync with server .

**That's it**

Answer (score -5):

All I could think of to do is minify them, not necessarily by hand, but manually so that the website does not have to process them.

The upside: Your site does not have to do this process now, it only has to load one big, already minified file.

The downside: Whenever you want to make edits to the code, you either have to do so in the giant, minified file, or make changes to your previous file, and then re-minify everything again.

If the pros outway the cons of this method for you, use something like (but not necessarily) http://cssminifier.com/

There are a million minifiers out there to choose from. A simple google search should yield these results.